# Error after adding second input statement to code

Tags: java, input, user-input

code_1

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Name : ");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("String name : " + name);
System.out.println("Enter age : ");
int age = input.nextInt();
```

code_2

Here I tried to get both and name and age at once. This code takes name and After I enter name and it prints error and doesn't ask for age...

```
System.out.println("Enter Name and age : ");
String name = input.nextLine();
int age = input.nextInt();//error may be over here

System.out.println("String name : " + name);
System.out.println("String name : " + age);
```

Comment: How and what inputs are you giving since it seems fine

Comment: What error does it print?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It would also help us if you could tell us exactly what error you are getting.

Comment: and Kevin beat me to it lol

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nextLine is reading everying, so nextInt has nothing to read. What you want to do is.

1.Read the input

2.Split by something (space for example)

3.Parse the text manualy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Try-with-resources so its closes the scanner.
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);) {

        System.out.println("Enter Name and age : ");
        // Read input, split by spaces.
        String[] text = input.nextLine().split(" ");
        String name = "";
        // Read the values, but not the last one.
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length - 1; i++) {
            name += text[i] + " ";
        }

        try {
            // Take the last one and convert it to int.
            int age = Integer.parseInt(text[text.length - 1]);
            // Print if everything was ok.
            System.out.println("String name : " + name);
            System.out.println("String name : " + age);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // The last field was not a number.
            System.err.println("Age has to be a number");
        }
    } // No catch propagate the exception.
}
```